# Get unique words from Spark Dataset in Java

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm using Apache Spark 2 to tokenize some text.

```
Dataset<Row> regexTokenized = regexTokenizer.transform(data);
```

It returns Array of String.

```
Dataset<Row> words = regexTokenized.select("words");
```

sample data looks like this.

```
+--------------------+
|               words|
+--------------------+
|[very, caring, st...|
|[the, grand, cafe...|
|[i, booked, a, no...|
|[wow, the, places...|
|[if, you, are, ju...|
```

Now, I want to get it all unique words. I tried out a couple of filters, flatMap, map functions and reduce. I couldn't figure it out because I'm new to the Spark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm coming from scala but I do believe that there's a similar way in Java.

I think in this case you have to use the `explode` method in order to transform your data into a `Dataset` of words.

This code should give you the desired results :

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.explode
val dsWords = regexTokenized.select(explode("words"))
val dsUniqueWords = dsWords.distinct()
```

For information about the explode methode please refer to the [official documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.packag)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

based on the @Haroun Mohammedi answer, I was able to figure it out in Java.

```
Dataset<Row> uniqueWords = regexTokenized.select(explode(regexTokenized.col("words"))).distinct();
uniqueWords.show();
```